# Silverlight 4 mousewheel press

Tags: silverlight

how can I capture mouse wheel click/press in Silverlight 4? I can detect its rolling using delta in mousewheel event, is there any way to detect its press? I use VS2010/C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouse wheel click would be a middle mouse button event.  Unfortunately the middle mouse button is not supported in Silverlight 4.  Consider alternatives such as cntrl + left click, especially as many computers won't have a middle mouse button.

Comment: It might be possible to do using some sort of COM API with a trusted oob application, but it wouldn't be something I'd recommend.